# Calling a RESTful web service using SSIS

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, rest, ssis

I need to call a RESTful web service using SSIS.

The web service accepts a JSON object as a parameter - I can call this service by constructing the JSON object using JavaScript:

```
data = {
    CustomerKey: "Demo",
    ApiKey: " 9999AA99-999A-9A9A-99A9-99999999A999",
    RegistrationNo: "REG N02",
    InsuranceRef: "Ins Ref",
    VehicleType: "Lorry",
    CarMake: "Car Make",
    CarModel: "Car Model",
    ChassisNo: "ChassisNo",
    GrossPlatedWeight: "GP weight",
    ManufactureYear: 1999,
    VehicleStatus: "Hired",
    DeliveryDate: null,
    TransferDate: new Date(2004, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0).toMSDate(),
    LastMotDate: new Date(2013, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0).toMSDate(),
    LastInspectionDate: new Date(2013, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0).toMSDate(),
    LastServiceDate: new Date(2014, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0).toMSDate(),
    InformationLog: "information log and more information",
    VehicleNotes: "Vehicle Notes",
    EntityReference: "reference",
    UseRootOrgUnit: "true",
    AddDictionaryItemIfMissing: "true"};
```

and posting the object to the web service.  The web service also returns a JSON object.

However, javascript is not available to me in SSIS - is it possible to call such a web service using SSIS?  If so, can anyone help me with a link to show the steps necessary? (I have no experience with SSIS).

Thanks.

Comment: How would you construct the JSON object using ".net language of your choice"? Same answer will apply to SSIS